# What's the difference between relying on Application's event mixin and Application.vent?

Tags: marionette

What's the point of `Application.vent` in Marionette?  The Application object already extends Backbone.Events, so I can write the following:

```
window.app = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
app.on("my:event", function() { console.log(arguments); });
app.trigger("my:event");
```

More easily than:

```
window.app = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
app.vent.on("my:event", function() { console.log(arguments); });
app.vent.trigger("my:event");
```

I've read the source and I can't tell the difference, but that doesn't mean there isn't one, and I'm half-willing to bet there's a good reason it's done the way it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `Application.vent`'s functionality does overlap `Application`'s built-in events, it adds more functionality than just a simple on/trigger event mechanism because it's an instance of [Backbone.Wreqr](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr). This adds command events and a request/response mechanism to allow modules to communicate to each other more easily.

It's still just events at the heart of it, but it aims to make inter-module communication a little easier to follow.

Comment: Ok, but nothing prevents me from using `Application.vent` when I want RequestResponse or Command behavior, rather than a simple event, does it? Or do they interact in some way that I'm not understanding?

Comment: Correct. `Application.vent`'s behavior is separate from `Application`'s simple event handling so you can choose which one to use depending on your needs.